# Is something wrong with the myOpenID

Tags: discussion, myopenid

I experienced some weird behaviour when I tried to login to stackoverflow.com, it gives me an error that repeats after I refresh the page and the login screen shows up again. This traps me in a cycle.

Eventually, it went through and I finally managed to log in.

What is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myopenid is only minimally supported by JanRain, so I recommend adding another email / provider to your account -- **remember, we now support an *unlimited* number of logins per account** -- so that you're covered in any case.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/

It is not unheard of for there to be occasional hiccups in their service, and I believe it is Amazon EC backed, so any Amazon EC outages can affect them as well.