# Lost badges, tags and flag weight after openID problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, user-accounts, openid

For the last three days I've been unable to log in to any of the Stack Exchange sites.

I use MyOpenID and I've been having this similar problem:
[Is something wrong with the myOpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119982/is-something-wrong-with-the-myopenid)

I made the mistake of adding (so I thought) a Stack Exchange login (my email + password + the same username). However, I think I created a new one that conflicts to the openID user that I managed to get working again.

But, I lost all my badges and tags (most of the badges are returning (with today's date)), and also my flag weight is lost:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164726/jackjoe?tab=summary

NOTE: This only happened on my SO account, all other accounts are ok!

**What can I do to return to my old state?** I just deleted the SE login and after several logouts am sure I have logged in with openID.

**UPDATE**:
The tags are back.
But I'm still missing two silver badges and one gold badge. I assume SO will "return" it as it did with the tags.
Also, I also lost all my tag preferences.
The flag weight, I can't be sure, I can't find it anywhere.

**UPDATE 2:**
Some days have passed since this happened, and from what I understand, the badges came at the same time (probably the way SO tried to solve this), but I definitely lost my Fanatic gold badge, Enthusiast silver badge and Deputy silver badge (this one denotes the loss of the flag weight).

**Is there an email I can write to, or some admin that can sort this, please?**

**UPDATE 3:**
The only thing that is missing is the Deputy silver badge (and so my flag weight), I'm now certain that I lost the flag weight and am in the process of "regaining" it by reviewing another 80 posts. It's not the best but I can live with that, because now I don't believe the flag weight + lost badge will return. By the way, each user ***can*** view their flag weight in their profile.

Comment: Flag weight isn't being shown to anyone anymore, period.

Comment: @PopularDemand ok thanks for the update, but I know I lost it, because I was reviewing an answer and only had 10 flags available (before I had much more).

Comment: @jackJoe You should be able to see be able to see your flag summary at http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1164726 but only you can see your own. Also the deputy and marshall badges have changed their requirements if that's what you were going for

Comment: 133 answers, 7 questions, and _no_ tag participation? Definitely seems like something is funny. I know The Stack caches data extensively, but that's just weird.

Comment: @ConradFrix thanks for the link (it shows only three flags, I had tens). I'm not *going for* any badge, I just want the ones I earned before...

Comment: I had a look and something is _definitely_ out of whack here. E-mail `team@stackoverflow.com`, I'll also ping some of the CC's to see what can be done about it (that e-mail receives a very large volume).

Comment: @TimPost Thank you! I just sent an email with a subject equal to this question's title.

Comment: Don't worry, there is still plenty of proverbial 'gold' to mine on Stack Overflow to regain your deputy badge in no time (sorry that it vanished!).

Comment: @TimPost true, and in some days I'll have it again, but it's sad that I lost it.

Comment: @jackJoe With your recent activity, I'd say that's a very good assertion :) Thanks for not getting discouraged!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Badges are not carried over during a merge due to sockpuppet concerns.  As you discovered, most badges will be awarded after the merge automatically.  Enthusiast and Fanatic are not, but we've manually taken care of that for you.

Tag preferences were not being carried over as part of a merge.  We've moved yours over, and are fixing up our code to handle this.

Flag history is not handled as part of our merge code.

Comment: Thanks Rebecca! I just noticed the badges are back (apart from the Deputy badge) but after reading you answer, does that mean that my flag history won't be "returned"? (and so my flag weight will remain this low and the lost Deputy badge is gone for good?)

Comment: Hi Rebecca, any news on my flag weight and Deputy badge?

Comment: Hi Rebecca, same things happened to me today. I lost my android and java gold badge and some other silver and bronze badge.. Should I expect those to come back soon?