# Lost badges in Stack Overflow account when added a new login, OpenID

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, login, openid

I had a total of 10 bronze badges when I had only one login using my company ID, but once I added my personal email ID for login, I just got the badges count in Stack Overflow reset to 7; today it got incremented to 8. But surprisingly reputation has not been affected.

It's just getting screwed up. Any idea how to get my badges back?

Comment: How do you know you had 10 badges?

Comment: What are the missing badges? You might repeat the actions to get them back.

Answer (score 0):

Do see this link:

[Lost badges, tags and flag weight after openID problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120058/248519)

and its answer is also nicely stated

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120916/248519

Comment: If you feel this is a dupe, just flag the post as such.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks harshalbenake. Also the links you suggested shows the bug but not a solution.

Comment: @Kailas: that's because apparently this is not a bug but a deliberate decision that some badges are not automatically merged when merging accounts. What badges exactly did you lose?